# Chaining observables in RxJS from an array into functions

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have a situtation where I have an array of values.

For each of these variables I want to call an observable, but only AFTER the previous observable completed.

Is there a more "RxJS" way of doing the following?

```
  let num = 0;

  let myObs = new Observable(observ => {
    observ.next(1);
  })
  let content=['x','y','z'];

  myObs.subscribe(data => {
    let i = 0;
    let that = this;
    let inlineFunc = function(){
      if ( i < content.length){
        that.gen(num).subscribe(() => {
          i++;
          inlineFunc();
        });
      }else{
        observer.next(doc);
      }
    };
    inlineFunc();
  });

  gen(num:number) : Observable < any >{
    return num*num;
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Observable.expand()`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/ts/core/linq/observable/expand.ts) if you want to continously and repetitively invoking the `observable`.

Suppose you have an array of content:

```
let content=['x','y','z'];
```

And for each of the values in content, you would want to call `gen()` function, which returns an Observable:

```
gen(num: number): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.of(num * num);
}
```

What you can do is

```
let myObs = Observable.of(1);
let num = 0;
let content = ['x','y','z'];

const gen = (num: number): Observable<any> => {
  return Observable.of(num * num);
}

myObs
.expand(()=>{
  return gen(num);
})
.skip(1)
.take(content.length)
.subscribe(x=>console.log(x));
```

Explanation:

1. `.expand()` will repititively calling the function pass to itself(as 1st argument), until you ask him to stop. In this case, it will call `gen()` (which returns an observable)
2. `.skip(1)` is to skip the first emission where your `myObs` is an observable with value 1.
3. `.take()` is to end the forever continuing `.expand()`. What it does here is, just repeat as many times as the length of the `content`.
4. `.subscribe()`to get the results.

**Comment**: You will get the following output:

```
0
0
0
0
```

because your `num` is 0. I am assuming `gen()` is just some dummy function that you will replace with some Observables that returns real meaningful data.

Working [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/zowijow/8/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 0):

You can first get an observable of value by using the from operator and then use   reduce,

```
Observable.from([...values])
    .reduce( this.reducingFn, 1 )
```

reducingFunction is a function that accept 2 parameters, the first is the starting value ( which is the second param in the reduce function ) and the second is the current value emitted by the outer stream ( each value in the values array )

```
// somewhere in you class
reducingFn( accumulatedValue, value){
    return accumulatedValue * value
}
```